# Какой движок выбрать для сайта бк?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Выбрал тему диплома разработку сайта по типу бк со всякой статистикой, вот стою перед выбором какой движок использовать. Нуждаюсь в вашем совете. Сайт полностью будет учебный, и больше для анализа статистики,  спортивных событий и должен демонстрировать возможность делать ставки виртуальной валютой. Выбрал тему такую, так как она мне показалась интересной и я опыта веб программирования вообще не имею. Еще если вы можете мне что то посоветовать , может какие то шаблоны связанные с моей темой, или еще что то, буду преблагодарен!

Comment: `https://developer.mozilla.org` посоветую

Answer (score 0):

При таких вводых я бы использовал исключительно Django или Flask. Вся мощь работы с данными от python + достаточно простые механизмы сериализации данных, встроенный шаблонизатор и уже из коробки достаточно неплохой уровень безопасности сайта.

Разворачивается достаточно просто и, как я уже сказал, все на пакетах)